# UISwitch is not working properly

Tags: ios, swift, uiswitch

I'm trying to implement one simple thing - to switch the string value by switching UISwitch.

But, I can get, what is wrong

```
        func switchIsChanged(interestedIn: UISwitch) {
            if interestedIn.on == true {
                print("UISwitch is ON")
            } else {
                print("UISwitch is OFF")
            }
        }

        if self.Gender.text == "male" {

            switchIsChanged(self.interestedIn)
  }
```

I can show the whole code if necessary. I just taking data from Facebook, understand the gender if user, and the set the value interestedIn depending on his or her gender.

```
import UIKit
import FBSDKShareKit
import FirebaseDatabase
import FirebaseAuth
import Firebase

class Settings: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var UserImage: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var UserName: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var UserSurname: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var Gender: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var interestedIn: UISwitch!
@IBOutlet weak var GenderofInsterest: UILabel!

var pictureURL : String?
var interest = ""

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    let paramets = ["fields": "email, first_name, last_name, picture.type(large), gender"]

    let graphRequest = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: paramets)

    graphRequest.startWithCompletionHandler({

        (connection, result, error) -> Void in

        if error != nil {
            print (error)
        }

        if let first_name = result["first_name"] as? String {

            self.UserName.text = first_name

        }

        if let last_name = result["last_name"] as? String {

            self.UserSurname.text = last_name

        }

        if let picture = result["picture"] as? NSDictionary, data = picture["data"] as? NSDictionary, pictureUrl = data["url"] as? String {

            self.pictureURL = pictureUrl

            let fbUrl = NSURL(string: pictureUrl)

            if let picData = NSData(contentsOfURL: fbUrl!) {
                self.UserImage.image = UIImage(data: picData)
            }

        }

        if let gender = result["gender"] as? String {

            self.Gender.text = gender

        }


        let people = ProfileClass()

        people.profileName = self.UserName.text
        people.profileGender = self.Gender.text
        people.profileSurname = self.UserSurname.text
        people.profilePhotoUrl = self.pictureURL
        people.SaveUser()


        func switchIsChanged(interestedIn: UISwitch) {
            if interestedIn.on == true {
                print("UISwitch is ON")
            } else {
                print("UISwitch is OFF")
            }
        }



        if self.Gender.text == "male" {

            switchIsChanged(self.interestedIn)

        }


    })



}}
```

Comment: I think what you want is a `Bool`, which can be true or false. `UISwitch` is an actual, GUI switch.

Comment: @ILkeTau Sorry I didn't  get U. UISwitch.on returns bool. Actually is not necessary to use UISwitch.on  == true, as I found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @ILideTau mentioned above, you should not directly work with UISwitch states, instead of that, just create a Bool variable, that will hold your switch state, and update UI when you change its state in didSet { } closure:

```
@IBOutlet weak var interestedInSwitch: UISwitch!

var interstedInState: Bool = false {
    didSet {
        interestedInSwitch.on = interstedInState
    }
}
func updateInterstedInState(newValue: Bool) {
  interstedInState = newValue
}
```